# Will Adobe Air allow me to "wrap" an existing HTML page to allow for drag-and-drop file upload?

Tags: flash, air

I have an HTML page (written in .NET MVC) that allows a user to upload a file and uses JQuery AJAX to load data from our application from which the user can select how to classify the file.  This all works fine, but I want to find a way to allow the user to drag-and-drop files on to it, but since the majority of users will only have Internet Explorer, I can't do strictly browser based solution as IE doesn't allow for drag and drop.

Therefore, after some research, I was thinking that Adobe's Air product might be a good option which will allow them to have a "widget" on their desktop that they can drag files to.  But after quite a bit of research on Adobe Air, I am getting more confused.  If someone can help me answer these questions, it will help me make sure I'm on the right path.

1) Can Adobe Air "wrap" an existing web page and interact with the elements on that page?  I am hoping to use my existing MVC code that has been tested and works and simply have a desktop container that allows for drag-and-drop and populates the `<input type="file">` element without having to convert to (and learn) ActionScript.

2) Is Adobe Air the best solution for what I have proposed?

3) I just installed Flash CS6, but I am a complete newbie to it.  Is this the best development platform for what I am trying to do?

4) Adobe provides a sample app called **[Snappy](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/scrappy_copy_paste.edu.html)** that seems like what I want, but when I downloaded it and tried to open up the "Scrappy.fla" file, it throws a warning stating "The target version of AIR SDK "AdobeAIR1_0" is not available.  The target will be set to the closest available version" and when I try to run it, it throws a hard error stating "Test Movie terminated. invalid application descriptor: versionNumber must have a non-empty value.".  Has anyone else experienced this error, and if so, how do I get it to run?

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, which I solved by copying all project layers with all their frames, and creating new flash project with Adobe Air settings. Then I pasted all the frames into the new project.

That worked for a while, but problem happened again, so I tried another solution:

I created new certificate from: `publish settings` -> `air settings` -> `signature`, and now it seems to work for me.